# PHP Regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I would like to capture the last folder in paths without the year. For this string path I would need just 'Millers Crossing' not 'Movies\Millers Crossing' which is what my current regex captures.

G:\Movies\Millers Crossing [1990]

```
preg_match('/\\\\(.*)\[\d{4}\]$/i', $this->parentDirPath, $title);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about [`basename` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) and [`substr` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) instead of complicated expressions?

```
$title = substr(basename($this->parentDirPath), 0, -6);
```

This assumes that there will always be a year in the format `[xxxx]` at the end of the string.

*(And it works on *nix too ;))*

**Update:** You can still use `basename` to get the folder and then apply a regular expression:

```
$folder = basename($this->parentDirPath);
preg_match('#^(.*?)(?:\[\d{4}\])?$#', $str, $match);
$title = $match[1];
```

Comment: @aLk: So how did you intend your expression to work then? It will only match if there is such a year.

Comment: Eventually it will look something like this ([\d{4}\]$)|(dvdrip$)|(...$) For now I was just wanting to find out how to skip those first few preceding slashes with regex but it looks like I should just be using basename then the regex.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
preg_match('/\\\\([^\\]*)\[\d{4}\]$/i', $this->parentDirPath, $title);
```

Basically, instead of matching any character with `.`, you're matching any character but `\`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want something like this:

```
/([^\\])+\s\[\d{4}\]$/
```

That's what I'd go with, at least. Should only include whatever comes after the last backslash in the string, and the movie title will be in the first capture group.

Answer (score 0):

Simpler approach:

```
([^\\]*)\s?\[\d{4}\]$
```

I believe your issue is also with you including "double backslashes" (e.g. `\\\\` instead of a single `\\`. You can also make life easier by using a class to include characters you **don't** want by prefixing it with a caret (`^`).